# how to retrieve data from SQL by entry.get() variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve data from SQL table by `entry.get()` function.

```
def display_1():
    global entry_1    
    x = entry_1.get()
    if x =="ball":
        objects = cursor.execute("select * from table where stuff=='ball' ") 
        for row in objects.fetchall():
            print("objects =", row[1],row[2],row[3])
```

I tried the code :`objects = cursor.execute("select * from table where stuff==x ")`
    but it doesn't work. I would use the x variable to retrieve data from database.

the full code is below:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('table.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.commit()
import tkinter as tk
def display_1():
    x = entry_1.get()
    if x =="ball":
        objects = cursor.execute("select * from table where stuff=='ball' ")
        for row in objects.fetchall():
            print("objects =", row[1],row[2],row[3])
root = tk.Tk()
entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)
btn_1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Display Text", command = display_1)
entry_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
btn_1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You will likely need to use a global variable here.

Comment: So with your updated code you are still having a problem? We need to see more code to see whats going on. Please provide your GUI code as well. A simplified version will work fine. Say your `entry_1` field and a button that calls your `display_1` functions should be enough.

Comment: you simply need to paste your code in, highlight it then press the code button. I can fix it for you but keep it in mind.

Comment: thank you so much Mike-SMT!

Comment: I have updated my answer let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your problem. I have updated my code to reflect your concern about the if statement. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: it works!!! I love you man

Comment: Glad we got there. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Based on your comments I have changed the function to work directly with the entry field. I used a `try/except` statement to handle a failed query.

Try this:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk


connection = sqlite3.connect('table.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.commit()

root = tk.Tk()

entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)

def display_1():
    try:
        # changed this to follow the safer example in the duplicate post.
        objects = cursor.execute("select * from table where stuff=?",(entry_1.get(),))
        for row in objects.fetchall():
            print("objects = {}".format((row[1], row[2], row[3])))
    except:
        print("query failed.")

btn_1 = tk.Button(root, text="Display Text", command=display_1)
entry_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
btn_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the OP doesn't want the `if` statement. They can't write an `if` statement for every possible value in the entry. Instead, they want to know how to directly use the variable in the query. That's why I marked it as a duplicate. This seems to have have nothing to do with tkinter, and everything to do with how to make a parameterized query.

Comment: Mike thank you again but I would remove   if x=="ball" and objects = cursor.execute("select * from table where stuff=='ball' ")  codes. for example, in sql theer are several objects: ball, bat, watch. I would write  bat in the gui form so my x variable ( x=entry_1.get()) store the word bat. now I would retrieve the values on sql by stuff == x selection . in this case stuff should be equal to bat.

Comment: @ bryan oakley. exactly

Comment: I see. Well I updated my example to only use the entry field without an if statement. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the info Bryan. I have updated my answer to use the entry field directly. I guess I miss understood the need and thought he was having a problem getting the data from the entry field.

Comment: Your code will work in some cases, but it opens the app up to an sql injection attack. I realize this is highly unlikely for a desktop app, but still, there are better ways to do a parameterized query. Your code will fail, for example, if the data in the widget contains a single quote.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hum. I am unfamiliar with security risk like that. I do not spend much time with SQL I will review the duplicate post to see if I can modify my code to be more secure.

Comment: @BryanOakley I changed the execute to be written in the same way as one of the answer mentioned would be more secure. Let me know if I am misunderstanding this.